# Vista Backup app with Linux/Samba

Tags: linux, backup, windows-vista, samba

I have been trying to make Vista Backup app work with a Linux/Samba shared drive.  I have Samba configured and can access it fine from the Vista box, including reads, writes and deletes.  However Vista Backup always ends up failing with error 0x81000006.  So is this possible?  Has anybody gotten this to work?  And if you have gotten it to work, will you paste your smb.conf file (my guess this is the problem)?

Thanks.

Comment: do you have any more information on how Vista Backup fails?  Ie. error messages?  Log messages?

Comment: What happens when you attempt from the Vista box to map a drive to a share you've listed in smb.conf?  Does it work by \\computername\sharename?  How about by \\ipaddress\sharename?

Comment: I can map both (by computername and by ipaddress) fine.

Comment: It doesn't appear to be a problem with Samba, there are very few reference to both Samba and this error, out on the internet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get Vista backup to work with Samba you need:

- Version 3.0.25 or above of Samba
- Have ACL support enabled in your Samba file system - to do so, add 'acl' to your mount command  LABEL=/backup /backup ext3 acl 1 2

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but no joy!  My Samba version is 3.3.2 and my mount looks like "/dev/sda1 on / type ext3 (rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro,acl) []".  Backups are still failing.

Comment: This is the correct answer.  I was unable to add ACL to my root partition I don’t know why, so my solution was to create a separate data partition and mount that with ACL enabled.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you can map the drive using either name or ip and sharename, and can rwdx the share, I suspect this is a problem with the vista box, not samba.  [This link](http://forum.soft32.com/windows/Vista-backup-problem-error-code-0x81000006-ftopict347880.html) has a few suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

How large are the files being backed up?  I know that there use to be a limitation of 2GB file sizes, and I haven't heard that it's been resolved.  I ended up going to NFS for backing up windows machines to a Linux box (via Unix Services for Windows to mount the NFS volume).  I don't know if that's pertinent to your situation or not, but I thought I'd throw it out there.